# How to create pull request using the Git Console and assign certain reviewer and message

Tags: git

What is the Git command which I could use to create pull request with specific comment and assign this pull request to specific reviewer?

According to the documentation I should use: `git request-pull [-p] <start> <url> [<end>]` but I don't see any arguments to specify reviewers.

I see this is possible as most of the UI's are allowing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git itself doesn't know what is a PR. That's Github specific. There's a tool with some extra git commands like those: https://github.com/github/hub

Comment: Actually I'm not working with GitHub but with TFS + Git. Nevertheless, seems like an answer to my question.